# Efficient uint32_t division on 8bit CPU

Tags: c++, c, atmega

I'm trying to improve a synchronization algorithm on an ATmega1284P. Whenever a synchronization event is triggered by some external hardware source, I need to measure the total cycles of an internal counter that have passed since the last sync event, divide that value by four and set this as the new counter overflow value that will trigger the corresponding counter IRQ. Thus I sync my counter to tick four times as fast as the external event source I'm syncing to.

In pseudocode, calculating the counter overflow value when the external event is received looks like this:

```
totalCounterCyclesSinceLastSync = counterCyclesSinceLastTick + counterCyclesPerTick * counterTicksSinceLastSync;
counterCyclesPerTick = totalCounterCyclesSinceLastSync / 4;
writeToRegister(counterCyclesPerTick);
counterTicksSinceLastSync = 0
```

While the CPU can't handle atomic arithmetic operations on more than 8 bits, the counter register that stores the overflow value is already 16 bits wide. This means that the variables in the pseudocode above need to be of `uint32_t`. As far as I know the ATmegaX series don't even have instructions for division of `uint8_t`, let alone variables four times the size. But since the application is time critical, I can't afford to waste hundreds or thousands of CPU cycles for some elaborate library calls to do this division.

So, here is my question: Do any of you know if I can count on elaborate compiler optimizations to translate this in the most efficient way? Or can you think of an (existing) algorithm for such an application?

**Some background on how the counter works**

The counter is a hardware counter integrated into the ATmega1284P chip, with it's counting frequency locked to the CPU speed with a fixed divider (e.g. 8). With every counter cycle, the counter value will be incremented by 1. When the counter "overflows", that is when it reaches `counterCyclesPerCounterTick`, the counter will tick, that is trigger the corresponding IRQ, where I can execute a short routine. Also, the counter value will be reset to 0 by the CPU. In this event, after performing my IRQ routine, I increment the value of `counterCyclesPassedSinceLastCounterTick` so that even after some counter ticks have passed (resulting in resets of the counter value) I know how much total counter cycles have passed.

If you need more info, please drop your question in the comments. I'm kind of a newbie in this field of low level programming, so I'm not sure if this is enough info to get a grasp of the problem.

Comment: Unsigned division by 4 (and any other power of 2) can be done with bit shifting. Any decent compiler should perform this optimization.

Comment: The elaborate library calls you refer to are likely better optimized than anything you'll come up with. They were likely written by someone with similar goals, but who wasn't new and knew the processor intimately.

Comment: That being said, use bit shifting

Comment: I know nothing about that target but couldn't you use the compiler to produce the function? [Example](https://godbolt.org/z/a66q54zKx). Division by 4 seems to mostly do some rotation magic.

Comment: Can you provide actual C code with variable declarations instead of this pseudo code. And please drop the ridiculously long identifiers, they aren't helping. One thing of note: `counterCyclesPerCounterTick ` appears to be a constant. Can't you simply define this constant to be 4 times smaller and skip the division?

Comment: Thank you all very much for your answers!! I just provided pseudocode since I guess many people might have good ideas (such as the bitshifting!), but wouldn't know cryptic instructions and register names from the ATmega libraries such as `TIMSK1 |= _BV(OCIE1A);`. I think I'll go with the bitshifting (there's actually an ASM instruction for it with this chip ) and also do the division before the adding and multiplying so I won't operate on `uint32_t` in the first place.

Comment: fwiw, i appreciated the names you used. That being said, based on what you said, namely " Do any of you know if I can count on elaborate compiler optimizations to translate this in the most efficient way", It sounds like this code hasn't even been written yet, let alone examined and performance tested to see if it meets your needs as-is. Personally, that should be your first step, because its sounds like you're prematurely optimizing to me.

Comment: I agree with Taekahn... it's hard to understand what kind of answer you are hoping to get here and how this answer would be useful to you.  You should think about how fast you need this code to run, then test the actual code in your system and see how fast it is actually running.  If the actual time is much faster than needed, then you're good.  If it's too slow, or just barely fast enough to work, then you can share your actual code ([mcve]) and measurements with us and ask for help optimizing it, but be sure to specify what your goal is.  We can't meaningfully optimize your pseudo code.

Answer (score 0):

As Lundin said just divide `counterCyclesPerTick` by 4. If that introduces too much error you can calculate the error as uint8_t and one to `counterCyclesPerTick` every time the errors is greater than 4. But overall I think more time will be spend on the multiplication than the division by 4 unless `counterCyclesPerTick` is a power of 2 or some other happy constant that optimizes really well.